# load a tabBar view before entering it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have two tabBar's, is there a way to load and by so prepare the view (it's an xml view) of the other tab while the user still didn't enter it (for faster loading) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using UITabBars, the load time should be inconsequential. If you're using one tab bar, but multiple tabs, and would like to preload the tabs, call [viewController view] to pre-load the view.

Comment: from where to call the [viewController view] ?

Comment: you'd call it from wherever you're setting up all your view controllers.